# gift ideas for an aspiring sound designer

Tags: gift

hello!

my boyfriend is graduating in a few weeks and will soon apply to a sound design program. i want to get him a basic starter kit with different tools he can use as he works on his portfolio. i've been reading some posts here, and i ordered the vmeter usb midi controller and zoom h1 recorder. i'm thinking about ordering the korg monotron as well.

are there other fun and useful gadgets out there that you suggest? or any comments about the items i already mentioned? i'm a noob, and i want to get some great stuff for him, though my budget is $200.

he checks this site often, so i'm worried he'll see this...

anyway, any recommendation/suggestion would be appreciated! thank you so very much!

Answer (score 4):

The Sounds of Star Wars makes a great gift, my wife bought me a copy when I graduated.

http://www.amazon.com/The-Sounds-Star-Wars-Rinzler/dp/0811875466/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1368713491&sr=8-1&keywords=The+Sounds+of+Star+Wars

Comment: I got the same present, great book.

Answer (score 4):

books are a great practical present eg

The Practical Art of Motion Picture Sound by David Lewis Yewdall 
http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Motion-Picture-Sound-Third/dp/0240808657/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1257540228&sr=8-1m

And if you got him a  recorder, then some fun physical sound props is a great idea

eg a thunder drum? (small drum with spring attached)
http://www.ebay.com/bhp/thunder-drum

or maybe a cheap violin bow

Plus some wind protection for the H1

http://www.rycote.com/products/mini_windjammer/mini_windjammer_for_portable_recorder/

http://www.rodemic.com/accessories/deadkitten

http://www.redheadwindscreens.com/

Answer (score 3):

You could go in another direction, instead of gear you could give him a "cool sound stuff kit". I don't think that buying gear is a good choice because these things can get really expensive and useless in a short time. But if your boyfriend is into sound design he probably will love to receive stuff that might look ridiculous (like some cellophane paper, bells and a broken tv he can smash and record later!) to everyone else, but are precious to a sound designer.

Answer (score 2):

As a girlfriend of a sound engineer (post, live, whatever) the biggest gift you can give is understanding and tolerance.

Understanding: sometimes it is hard for a partner to accept that the sound-guy/girl is lot's of time on the run. For a soundguy/girl it's also hard to be away or in the studio all the time but it's harder to know that the partner is not accepting this.

Tolerance: be tolerant if he/she falls asleep at you're parents sunday morning lunch because he worked until 4 o'clock in a dark/dirty/loud rock-club/studio and has a big headache.

Don't buy him any tools. The good one are expansive.

Invite him in the cinema. Or: Give him a box of beer, men likes beer.

Best

Guido

Comment: True, it is often hard for non-sound people to understand how sound people function. There can be times in post where we "disappear off the grid" for weeks or months at a time, and often not allowed to speak about what we're doing (NDAs). So it can often put us in the precarious position of seeming like we're rude or avoiding the world, when actually it's not at all - just the nature of the gig and how non-souns people interpret our "abnormal" behavior.

Comment: Happy birthday! I got you some understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This should fit on your budget just fine :D

http://www.zazzle.com/well_fix_it_in_post_button-145659223402657610

But all kidding aside, I'd say focus on the sorts of stuff which empower him to explore sound in his own way (such as a recorder, etc) like it sounds that you're doing.  Everyone's journey in sound is different, and sometimes the best gift is the one which offer them the opportunity to be empowered to explore their inspiration (case in point: having a means and medium to record any sounds to begin with opens up the entire world to explore, things to capture and listen to, how to creatively make new sounds, etc.  I know my path just got that much more "cheerier" and fun when I could finally walk around with a means not only to say "oh, that sounds cool" but actually press the button and say "awesome, let's record this - I can use it for something" (well, not in that order because you'd ruin the take hah).

Answer (score 0):

From experience, the best gift you can do is a simple "long hours are OK" statement, and to really mean it. That costs $0 of money.

If you wish to gift an experience, arrange a visit to an anechoic chamber or any other sound/signal lab.

Gifting a "thing"? How about a Jezz Riley French hydrophone?

Comment: my wife got me a pair of the JRF hydrophones one year and it was total success on her part.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Guido. Another thing you can do is try and take an interest in the world of sound and learn about this wonderful world and why we spend hours locked away on projects. You'd be surprised how inspirational it can be to have the one you love take an interest and share in your passion.

I am so glad you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to a big toyshop and buy some sound making toys: voice changers, megaphones etc. - anything that'll make interesting sounds.

Oh and the little Korg is great fun.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that presents can get very expensive very quickly. These are my 'dont break the bank' ideas :)

• Small Peli micro case, or any small, tough case to store stuff

• Vecro straps and cable management gear

• Griddit organiser

• In-line attentuators

• piezo transducers

• old ebay mics he can trash in the line of duty

• and at £25 each, I still cant praise manfrotto super clamps enough. Very handy.